# How do I plot specific functions in pyplot as well as display chi-squared values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, chi-squared

Let me preface this by saying I am a total newbie to Python/programming. I need to do this for a research course I'm taking and it can be rough.

Anyways, I can't seem to understand how I can plot specific functions using pyplot (the functions are defined elsewhere in my code, but retrieving them for plotting is proving difficult. Also, how can I display the chi-squared value on each graph?
Thanks!

```
# Chi-square HW 03/25/2015

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(7)
y = np.array([2, 6, 11, 15, 28, 41, 60])
sigma = np.array([2.1, 0.26, 0.31, 1.55, 0.42, 1.05, 2.1])


# Linear
def lin(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    lin = a +b*x
    ymod = lin(x,a,b)
    chisq = ((ymod - y)/sigma) **2
    return np.sum(chisq)
    print np.sum(chisq)

# Quadratic
def quad(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    quad = a + b*x + c*x^2
    ymod = quad(x,a,b,c)
    chisq = ((ymod - y)/sigma) **2
    return np.sum(chisq)
    print np.sum(chisq)

# Exponential
def expn(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    expn = a * exp(b*x) + c
    ymod = expn(x,a,b,c)
    chisq = ((ymod - y)/sigma) **2
    return np.sum(chisq)
    print np.sum(chisq)

# Power-law
def pwr(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    pwr = a * x^b + c
    ymod = pwr(x,a,b,c)
    chisq = ((ymod - y)/sigma) **2
    return np.sum(chisq)
    print np.sum(chisq)


#Minimization
def LinRes():
    LinRes = minimize(lin, 0, vars, method='Powell' )
    return LinRes

def QuadRes():
    QuadRes = minimize(quad, 0, vars, method='Powell')
    return QuadRes

def ExpnRes():
    ExpnRes = minimize(expn, 0, vars, method='Powell')
    return ExpnRes

def PwrRes():
    PwrRes = minimize(pwr, 0, vars, method='Powell')
    return PwrRes







#Linear Plot
plt.figure(1)
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=sigma, linestyle ='None')
plt.plot(xmod,ymod,'k-')
plt.title('Linear')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Linear_Plot.png')

#Quadratic Plot
plt.figure(2)
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=sigma, linestyle ='None')
plt.plot(xmod,ymod,'k-')
plt.title('Quadratic')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Quadratic_Plot.png')

#Exponential Plot
plt.figure(3)
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=sigma, linestyle ='None')
plt.plot(xmod,ymod,'k-')
plt.title('Exponential')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Exponential_Plot.png')

#Power-law Plot
plt.figure(4)
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=sigma, linestyle ='None')
plt.plot(xmod,ymod,'k-')
plt.title('Power-law')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Power_Law_Plot.png')
```

Comment: You don't plot functions, you plot data  -- e.g., `plt.plot([1,2,3],[5,1,3])` -- so you want to *return* data from your functions. Either pass in x-values (like [1,2,3]) and return y-values (e.g. [5,1,3]) or return both x- and y- values (you can return two things: `return x, y`).

Comment: also, your functions `lin`, `quad`, etc call themselves. You need to work through a simple tutorial on Python functions for this to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the code below that corrects your functions and your plots (if I understood correctly what you intend to do). I did not try to fix your minimization attempt, but maybe some of these comments will help you.

The most obvious corrected mistakes are the following:

- It's not clear whether you want your functions to return the data models or the sum of chi-squared values. A suggestion is to have a function to generate the data models (ymod) and another one to calculate the chi-squared sum (see an example in the code below).
- Your print statement inside a function has to be before the return statement. Otherwise it will never be reached by the code (and furthermore is an error).
- plt.plot receives data points, not functions. If you want to plot func(x) you need to provide the data pairs as e.g. plt.plot(x, func(x)).

This is a bit closer now. I believe you can take it from there.

```
# Chi-square HW 03/25/2015

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp
from scipy.stats import chi2
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x = np.arange(7)
y = np.array([2, 6, 11, 15, 28, 41, 60])
sigma = np.array([2.1, 0.26, 0.31, 1.55, 0.42, 1.05, 2.1])


# Linear
def lin(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    return a + b*x

# Quadratic
def quad(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    return a + b*x + c*x**2

# Exponential
def expn(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    return a * np.exp(b*x) + c

# Power-law
def pwr(vars):
    a,b,c = vars
    return a * x**b + c


# A generic function for chi-squared values could be the following
def chisq_fun(fun, vars):
    return np.sum(((fun(vars) - y)/sigma) ** 2)





#Minimization
def LinRes():
    LinRes = minimize(lin, 0, vars, method='Powell' )
    return LinRes

def QuadRes():
    QuadRes = minimize(quad, 0, vars, method='Powell')
    return QuadRes

def ExpnRes():
    ExpnRes = minimize(expn, 0, vars, method='Powell')
    return ExpnRes

def PwrRes():
    PwrRes = minimize(pwr, 0, vars, method='Powell')
    return PwrRes




vars = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)  # (a, b, c)

plt.title('Linear')
plt.subplot(411)
plt.xlabel('x (independent variable)')
plt.ylabel('lin(%s, %s, %s)' % vars)
plt.plot(x, lin(vars), 'o', linewidth=2.0, color='k')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=sigma, linestyle='None')

plt.title('Quadratic')
plt.subplot(412)
plt.xlabel('x (independent variable)')
plt.ylabel('quad(%s, %s, %s)' % vars)
plt.plot(x, quad(vars), 'o', linewidth=2.0, color='k')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=sigma, linestyle='None')

plt.title('Exponential')
plt.subplot(413)
plt.xlabel('x (independent variable)')
plt.ylabel('expn(%s, %s, %s)' % vars)
plt.plot(x, expn(vars), 'o', linewidth=2.0, color='k')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=sigma, linestyle='None')

plt.title('Power-law')
plt.subplot(414)
plt.xlabel('x (independent variable)')
plt.ylabel('pwr(%s, %s, %s)' % vars)
plt.plot(x, pwr(vars), 'o', linewidth=2.0, color='k')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=sigma, linestyle='None')

plt.show()

(a, b, c) = vars
print("Chi-squared sum for lin(%s, %s, %s) is %f" % (a, b, c, chisq_fun(lin, vars)))
print("Chi-squared sum for quad(%s, %s, %s) is %f" % (a, b, c, chisq_fun(quad, vars)))
print("Chi-squared sum for expn(%s, %s, %s) is %f" % (a, b, c, chisq_fun(expn, vars)))
print("Chi-squared sum for pwr(%s, %s, %s) is %f" % (a, b, c, chisq_fun(pwr, vars)))
```